# Cassandra: clear prepared statement cache

Tags: cassandra

We are changing a data type of primary key of a table in Cassandra. Due to this, an application which is using prepared statement on this table is failing.

Is there any way to clear prepared statement cache without restarting Cassandra?

Comment: Please help me on the below issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134514/cassandra-querying-reducing-performance/52139204?noredirect=1#comment91235494_52139204

Answer (score 1):

What version are you using? this is a bug in Cassandra:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-8652

Upgrading may solve the problem but there is no mechanism that I am aware of to clear this short of restarting the service.